# Function isn't working like it should. The execution stops

Tags: c, function

I am a beginner in c and i was writing this piece of code. This is the first time im using doubles so it might be related.

The code gives the print statement in the main function, then when it enters my function ReadVector() it stops working.

I want to to learn and fix my mistake, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void ReadVector(double *x,int size){

printf("Enter the values of vector: \n");

for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    scanf("%f",*(x + i));


}


int main(){

int m;
printf("Enter the size of vector: ");
scanf("%d",m);

double *arr= (double*)malloc(m*sizeof(double));

ReadVector(arr,m);


}
```

Comment: At least use  scanf("%d",&m);

Comment: Please also check the scanf exit code.

Comment: the specifier for double in scanf is `"%lf"`... `scanf("%lf", &x[i])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

  void ReadVector(double *x,int size){

       printf("Enter the values of vector: \n");

       for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        scanf("%lf", &x[i]); 


}


int main(){

   int m;
   printf("Enter the size of vector: ");
   scanf("%d",&m);

   double *arr= (double*)malloc(m*sizeof(double));

   ReadVector(arr,m);


}
```

Comment: use `"%lf"` to scanf doubles; scanf into a pointer, not into a value

Comment: `scanf("%lf",*(x + i)); ` is not exact. and do not cast `malloc`